# Can every convergent series uniformly converge in some way?

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence

I found myself thinking on this idea for a long time, I really not understand the intuition of the difference between uniform convergence and convergence. But when I thought on the definition deeply, I figured that

If I have convergence of $f_n$ so I know for every $x\in A$ and for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is $N$ such that for every $n>N$ $$|f_n-f|<\epsilon$$

but if I take the $N=\max[{N_i}]$ I get exactly the definition of the uniform convergebce.

Is it correct? what is the motivation to define just convergence, or uniform convergebce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you wrote $N=max[{N_i}]$, you're silently omitting on which set the index $i$ belongs to. In the case of real maps, you have in fact $i \in \mathbb R$, an infinite set. In that case, $N=max[{N_i}]$ may not be defined.

**Some examples**

Take for $f_n(x) = 1/n$ a map not depending on $x$. In that case, everything is fine.

Now take $f_n(x) = x^n$ defined on the interval $[0,1]$... I let you define the $N_i$ of your question and figure out that $$N=max[{N_i}]$$ is not defined, or said in another way has to be infinite.

Comment: ohh, I understand how my assumption was wrong now and I also now understand better the difference between uniform and none uniform converge.
according to $f_n(x) = x^n$ why  $N=max[{N_i}]$ is not define? I still can't understand it

Comment: @Sagigever Take $0 < x <1$ and $\epsilon >0$. Then try to find $N_x$ such that $0 \le x^n < \epsilon$ for $n > N_x$. I let you do that, it is a good exercise. You should see that the closer $x$ is from $1$, the higher $N_x$ should be. Also, please answer to the question: why do you use $i$ for the index? To which set does $i$ belong to?

Comment: Ok now I understand what you meant, and about the $i$, yes I didn't think that there is actually infinite value for every interval thus because there is infinite numbers there.
thank you, you helped me a lot!